# Calling minicart in phtml not showing dropdown on click

Tags: checkout, phtml, mini-cart, custom-theme, drop-downs

I'm calling minicart in my phtml like below

```
<?php  echo $this->getLayout()
          ->createBlock('Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Sidebar')
          ->setTemplate('Magento_Checkout::cart/minicart.phtml')
          ->toHtml(); ?>
```

But When I click on cart icon drop down is not showing. I inspected the dom there is not drop down ui widgets.